# XPath Statement doesn´t return value, but true or false

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, opc-ua

After adding the namespaces with the function:

`var select = useNamespaces({ns1: "http://pippo.com/schema"})`

I use the following statement:

```
var Objects = select("//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[@ReferenceType="+typeofref+"]/text()="+id.toString(), ns);
```

The output that I want is All References with ReferenceType = typeofref and text() = id

The output that I get is : True

It seems like it founds something but It just says that there is the element , but It doesn´t retrieve it. Does anybody know why?

The xm file is this one:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/master/Robotics/Opc.Ua.Robotics.NodeSet2.xml

Comment: The answer is: False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath ends with a `=` + *some string*, and so will only ever return `true` or `false`.

Change

```
"//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[@ReferenceType="+typeofref+"]/text()="+id.toString()
```

to

```
"//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[@ReferenceType="+typeofref+" and .="+id.toString()+"]"
```

in order to select all `ns1:References/ns1:Reference` elements with `typeofref` values for the `@ReferenceType` attribute and a string value of `id.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I have another issue: I would like to get the grandparent of the element (UAObject->References->Reference). Do you know which is the best solution? I tried with ancestor::UAObject but it gives me an empty result

Comment: You're welcome.  I'd recommend posting a new question with a [mcve] regarding your issue with `ancestor::`.  Thanks.

Comment: Solved easily with ```var Objects = select("//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[@ReferenceType="+typeofref+" and .="+id.toString()+"]/../..", ns);```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Your `ancestor::UAObject` attempt may have failed to select anything due to `UAObject` being in a namespace, but I wanted to see a full [mcve] to answer for sure.  Fyi, it's ok to use namespace prefixes with explicit axis, e.g: `ancestor::ns1:UAObject` will select all `ns1:UAObject` ancestors of the current node.

Comment: Hey, I used ancestor::ns1:UAObject as you said. It works
What If I want to select just an element of a xml tag? I used this statement:

 Objects.id  = select(
      "//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[@ReferenceType=" +
        typeofref +
        " and .=" +
        id.toString() +
        "]/ancestor::ns1:UAObject[@NodeId]",
      ns,
      false
    );

Comment: Please post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhuges have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753920/xpath-take-element-on-double-condition