# XPath take element on double condition

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, opc-ua

I have an InformationModel from OPC-UA, written in xml (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/blob/v1.04/Robotics/Opc.Ua.Robotics.NodeSet2.xml).
From this model I want to:
Look at the reference inside an UAObject and get the DisplayName only if the reference has
1)The nodeid I am looking for
2)Has a field IsRecursive="false"

I tried this code for getting all object with a reference which point to my specified nodeid and it works.
Here it is the code for it:

```
var ObjectsName2 = select(
    "//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[.=" +
      formatted_id + "]/ancestor::ns1:UAObject/ns1:DisplayName/text()",
    nodes,
    false
  );
```

Now I want to take the one that has the specific nodeid and has field IsForward setted to "false".
So I have a double condition that needs to be verified with an AND.
Here it is the code I am using:

```
var formatted_id = '"' + ParentNodeId + '"';
  var negate = "false";
  var ObjectsName = select(
    "//ns1:References/ns1:Reference[.=" +
      formatted_id + 
      "//@ns1:IsForward="+negate+"]/ancestor::ns1:UAObject/ns1:DisplayName/text()",
    nodes,
    false
  );
```

The wrong result is an empty array.
To make a bit easier to understand here it is an example that shows what I want.

Imagine you have this xml entry and the node that I am looking for is ns=1;i=15008:

```
<UAObject NodeId="ns=1;i=15024" BrowseName="2:ParameterSet" ParentNodeId="ns=1;i=15008">
   <DisplayName>ParameterSet</DisplayName>
   <Description>Flat list of Parameters</Description>
   <References>
     <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;i=15061</Reference>
     <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=58</Reference>
     <Reference ReferenceType="HasModellingRule">i=78</Reference>
     <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=15008</Reference>
   </References>
 </UAObject>
```

As you can see there is a Reference called "HasComponent" which points to my node (ns=1;i=15008) and IsForward="false".

The expected output should be the display name of the UAObject in the output array -->ParameterSet
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply based on xpath alone, this expression:

```
//Reference[@ReferenceType="HasComponent"][@IsForward="false"]
```

should select `ns=1;i=15008` in your sample xml.

Answer (score 2):

so you want to find the `Reference` node that has `ReferenceType` is `HasComponent` and `IsForward` is `false`, from that, go up 1 level find the `DisplayName` ?

```js
const {transform} = require('camaro')

;(async function main() {
    const xml = `
    <UAObject NodeId="ns=1;i=15024" BrowseName="2:ParameterSet" ParentNodeId="ns=1;i=15008">
        <DisplayName>ParameterSet</DisplayName>
        <Description>Flat list of Parameters</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;i=15061</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=58</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasModellingRule">i=78</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent" IsForward="false">ns=1;i=15008</Reference>
        </References>
    </UAObject>
    `
    const template = {
        names: ['//References/Reference[@ReferenceType="HasComponent" and @IsForward="false"]', '../../DisplayName']
    }
    console.log(await transform(xml, template), null, 4);
})()
```

out

```
{ names: [ 'ParameterSet' ] }
```

Comment: Which library are you using? I am using xpath from npm

Comment: @AndreaFresa it's camaro. I wrote it to scratch my own itch https://github.com/tuananh/camaro

Comment: Do you have also a solution for xpath? All my code use the xpath library and it is a problem to change it

Comment: it's should be similar `//References/Reference[@ReferenceType="HasComponent" and @IsForward="false"]`